# SSH Amazon EC2: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

Hello I am trying the command below to connect to a new ec2 instance. However I cannot connect (some bits edited to hide personal details)

```
ssh -i blugg.pem ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xx-x.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com -v -l blugg

OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-xx-xxx-xx-x.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [54.200.44.9] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file blugg.pem type -1
debug1: identity file blugg.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 70:71:f0:f0:33:b5:a
debug1: Host 'ec2-xx-xxx-xx-x.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/bluggHome/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/bluggHome/.ssh/blugg.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: blugg.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
Aaron-Lotes-Air:.ssh bluggHome$ ssh -i blugg.pem ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-x.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com -v -l blugg
```

Comment: Fixed, username to connect with is 'ec2-user'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-l ec2-user or ec2-user@ fixes this.